# Number of AVL Search Trees with n Nodes and x Leaves?

Tags: python, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes, avl-tree

This question was asked a few years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500560/number-of-ways-to-create-an-avl-tree-with-n-nodes-and-l-leaf-node) but there was no correct answer given.

I know that a tree is AVL balanced if for any node the heights of its left and right subtree differ by no more than one.

Given a certain number (let's call it n) of nodes, with a certain number (let's say x) being leaves, how many distinct AVL-balanced tree shapes have n nodes and x leaves?

For example, [there are two tree shapes for 5 nodes and 3 leaves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8rso.png).

I have attempted to implement the accepted answer to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99085/the-number-of-balanced-trees-with-n-node-and-l-leaves) in python in my function `num_trees_w_height` which is then used to calculate the total number of trees of any height in `num_trees`. Here is my code so far:

```
def num_trees_w_height(height, nodes, leaves):
    if nodes == 0 or leaves == 0:
        return 0
    if height > math.log(nodes,2) or leaves > nodes//2+1:
        return 0
    if height == 0:
        return 1
    for h in range(0,height+1):
        for n in range(0,nodes+1):
                return num_trees_w_height(h-1,n,l)\
                    *num_trees_w_height(h-1,nodes-n,leaves-l)\
                    +num_trees_w_height(h-1,n,l)\
                    *num_trees_w_height(h-2,nodes-n,leaves-l)\
                    +num_trees_w_height(h-2,n,l)\
                    *num_trees_w_height(h-1,nodes-n,leaves-l)

def num_trees(nodes, leaves):
    num=0
    for height in range(0,nodes):
        num += num_trees_w_height(height,nodes,leaves)
    return num
```

However, when I call `num_trees(5,3)` I get a TypeError saying that my recursive return statement is attempting to multiply an `int` and a `NoneType` and when I call `num_trees_w_height(3,5,3)` I get 0. Both of these calls should return 2 as demonstrated in my example above.

Comment: [Related](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/26027/number-of-different-avl-tree). [Even more related](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99085/the-number-of-balanced-trees-with-n-node-and-l-leaves). Just FYI: StackOverflow is **not** the best place to ask computer science questions. StackOVerflow is about fixing *programming* problems (mostly). There are dedicated StackExchange sites for computer science.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thank you for the help! I have attempted to implement the algorithm given to those questions and added that above.